# in python: How to print message with the number of expected names started with lowercase

Tags: python, while-loop, do-while

here I have to print friends names that start with upper letter only and
except names with lowercase
and then print message with the number of expected names started with lowercase

I need to know if my code is right or there is another easy way to print expected lower name ??

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]

num =0

arr = []
while num < len(friends):
    if friends[num] != friends[num].lower():
        print(friends[num])
    num += 1    
else:
    
    mis = 0
    while mis < len(friends):
        if friends[mis].islower():
            arr.append(friends[mis])
        mis += 1
    print(f"all names have printed and the num of lower name is {len(friends) - len(arr)-1}")
```

Comment: your code is not working properly.
try with this data

friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "sherif"]

Comment: you can calculate the lower name from only len(arr) not len(friend) - len(arr) - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to check whether the name begins with a lower/upper case, then you can use a list comprehensions like below to do this:

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]

upper_case = [print(name) for name in friends if name.strip()[0].isupper()]
print(f'Total lower case names: {len(friends) - len(upper_case)}')
```

This would also work if the names had a trailing whitespace. Also, using a `for` loop in your sample would be more apt instead of maintaining a separate counter with a `while` loop. The loop which you have is basically a `for` loop, but with extra steps.

Comment: thanks @charchit for you helping the code is very simple and not complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the relevant friends with `filter`:

`list(filter(lambda name: name[0].islower(), friends))`

then you can use `len` to see how many